# How to redirect to another site from SwaggerUI Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, http, redirect, https, swagger-ui

I need to create an endpoint that will be visible in the SwaggerUI(the controller must be RestController) when executed, which will redirect me from the swagger to, for example, https://google.com page.

I tried the following variations of methods:

```java
    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Void> redirect() {
        return ResponseEntity
                .status(HttpStatus.FOUND)
                .location(URI.create("https://google.com"))
                .build();
    }
```

```java
    @GetMapping
    public void redirect(HttpServletResponse httpResponse) throws IOException {
        httpResponse.sendRedirect("https://google.com");
    }
```

```java
    @GetMapping
    public RedirectView redirect() {
        return new RedirectView("https://google.com");
    }
```

All of these methods work if I make a request through Postman or directly into the search bar. However, when I make a request through Swagger, I get a response as a result:

```
Failed to fetch.
Possible Reasons:
- CORS
- Network Failure
- URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.
```

I also added the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header with a value of `*` to all these requests, but this did not affect the result at all